# MAX17703 Li-ion battery charger: max. battery voltage enough for 15 cells in series?

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger

I am designing a battery charger for 15 Li-ion cells in series that add up to 63 V when fully charged.

I have shortlisted a charger controller IC from Maxim, the [MAX17703](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX17703.pdf).

The IC provides output voltages up to 60 V (-2.1 V). Will this be sufficient to fully charge the battery pack?

Comment: Tip: make the question topic descriptive enough that people who know about the topic will be attracted to reading it. "Battery charger" doesn't really achieve this. Try "MAX17703 battery charger max. battery voltage". But if you need 63 V and it's only capable of 60 V why are you asking?

Comment: Why are you stuck on this?  Start with proper design specs in your question  Vin range, Vout range, I out max.   etc  This chip is limited by the input not the output.

Comment: How do you intend to monitor and balance 15 cells?  (Hint bad idea)

Comment: You have much to learn about battery packs https://batteryuniversity.com/articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAX17703's maximum input voltage is 60 V, the maximum programmable output voltage is 60 - 2.1 = 57.9 V, which will charge 15 cells in series to 3.86 V each.

So no, it will not *fully* charge your 15-cell Li-ion battery pack.

If you are willing to take the risk of supplying an input voltage very close to this IC's Absolute Maximum Rating, you would get just about enough output voltage for 15 cells, but you really shouldn't go there.

It would be better to find another charger IC, or use a smaller battery pack.